# Error 1136 en MySQL en con código generado por MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo un problema al intentar insertar datos a una tabla MySQL, incluso si lo hago desde el Workbench, que se supone genera el código automáticamente.

El Workbench me genera este código:

```
INSERT INTO `agendame`.`doctores` (`usuarios_id_usuarios`, `nombre`, `apellido_paterno`, 
`apellido_materno`,`codigo_postal`, `domicilio_calle`,`domicilio_numero_calle`, 
`domicilio_colonia`,`celular`, `telefono_fijo`, `email`, `ciudad`, `estado`, 
`fecha_nacimiento`, `especialidad`, `cedula`, `hora_inicio`, `hora_salida`) VALUES 
( '41', 'Dr. Nahim Rgz', 'RGz', 'cadena', '31100', 'calle', '17110', 'quinta san miguel', 
'6142561234', '6132564236', 'nahim@correo.com', 'Chihiahua', 'Chihuahua', '1994-11-27', 
'Programador', '12554536', '08:00:00', '19:00:00');
```

y este es el mensaje de error:

> ERROR 1136: 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

entiendo que el error indica que no coinciden el numero de columnas con el numero de datos a ingresar pero ya busque y no veo que en mi código se me haya olvidado alguna coma.

Tabla en la que quiero insertar los datos:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `doctores`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `doctores` (
  `id_doctor` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuarios_id_usuarios` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_paterno` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido_materno` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_postal` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `domicilio_calle` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `domicilio_numero_calle` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `domicilio_colonia` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `celular` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `telefono_fijo` bigint(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `ciudad` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `especialidad` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `cedula` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `hora_inicio` time DEFAULT '08:00:00',
  `hora_salida` time DEFAULT '18:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_doctor`),
  KEY `fk_doctores_usuarios1_idx` (`usuarios_id_usuarios`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_doctores_usuarios1` FOREIGN KEY (`usuarios_id_usuarios`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id_usuarios`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: Que es esto? `agendame`.`doctores`   ... Son 2 tablas? o estas concatenando alguna cadena?

Comment: agendame es la base de datos y doctores es la tabla

Comment: Lo que dice es que la cantidad de valores no coincide con la cantidad de columnas

Comment: entiendo perfectamente, pero revisa el código, le digo que serán 18 columnas y le mando los 18 valores, ya revisé y no eh omitido ninguna coma

Comment: Podrías poner la estructura de tu tabla?

Comment: listo, ya lo agregue

Comment: @NahimRgz el campo `apellido_materno` no existe, se llama `apelido_materno`

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez perdón, ese error ya lo solucioné

Comment: Si no es ese no hay falla, lo probe y funciona bien

Answer (score -1):

has intentado quitarle las comillas simples a las columnas? yo por lo general las declaro sin nada. Ej.

```
INSERT INTO doctores (usuarios_id_usuarios, nombre, apellido_paterno, 
apellido_materno, codigo_postal, domicilio_calle, domicilio_numero_calle, 
domicilio_colonia, celular, telefono_fijo, email, ciudad, estado, 
fecha_nacimiento, especialidad, cedula, hora_inicio, hora_salida) VALUES 
( '41', 'Dr. Nahim Rgz', 'RGz', 'cadena', '31100', 'calle', '17110', 'quinta san miguel', 
'6142561234', '6132564236', 'nahim@correo.com', 'Chihiahua', 'Chihuahua', '1994-11-27', 
'Programador', '12554536', '08:00:00', '19:00:00');
```

Comment: si, ya lo intente y el error sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: Otro posible problema sería que estés tratando de almacenar un tipo de valor string y lo pases como integer u otro tipo por ejemplo:

INSERT INTO doctores (nombre) VALUES 
($doctor);

Cuando debería de ser:
INSERT INTO doctores (nombre) VALUES 
('$doctor');

Answer (score -1):

el error lo estaba causando un `TRIGGER` configurado para ejecutarse después de hacer un `INSERT`a la tabla doctores. 
Gracias a todos